# Use Java 8 Streaming to convert List<Map> to Map<String,List<Map>>, using value as key

Tags: java, java-8, maps, grouping, java-stream

Input:

```
[
   {
     "A": "valToGroup_1",
     "B": "xxx"
   },
   {
     "A": "valToGroup_1",
     "B": "yyy"
   },
   {
     "A": "valToGroup_2",
     "B": "zzz"
   }
]
```

Output:

```
"valToGroup_1":[
    {"A": "valToGroup_1",
     "B": "xxx"
    },
    {"A": "valToGroup_1",
     "B": "yyy"
    }
]
"valToGroup_2":
[
  {"A": "valToGroup_2",
   "B": "zzz"
  }
]
```

That is, given a List input, where each entry is a map I would like to return a grouping by a specific corresponding value of a key shared across all maps.

Assumptions:

- All maps will have that key
- All keys in the maps are strings

I figured it was straightforward without using streaming:
iterate through the list, grab "A"'s value, and add/create an entry, but I think it would be a good lesson in streaming and could lead to cleaner code.

Comment: _"I think it would be a good exercise in streaming"_ -- what are you waiting for? Go to it. Also visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: Should the third entry have `"B": "zzz"`?

Comment: yup. thanks for pointing that out. it was to clarify that "B"'s values may be unique, but is wholly irrelevant.

Comment: Mostly just curious: You are introducing a redundancy in your output data structure. Why not just `Map<String,List<String>>` (having only the `B`s in the lists)?

Answer (score -1):

```
Map<String, List<Map<?, ?>>> map = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.get("A").toString()));
```

Comment: Trying to guess, the asker said “I think it would be a good lesson in streaming”, so maybe someone thought the best lesson would be if the asker wrote the code himself. It’s a line that’s hard to draw in this case, though.

Comment: I wouldn’t go so far that a “a good lesson in streaming” always requires the OP to do it entirely himself, but a code-only answer to this is going into the wrong direction, for sure.

Comment: @Holger I'm calling `toString()` on a value, not a key.

Comment: Oh right. It’s filling a gap in the OP’s description.